# How to catch a exception thrown inside of a JTA-Transaction?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, jta

I'm using Spring 3.0.5, Hibernate 3.6.7 and Atomikos Transactionessentials 3.7.0. Transactions configured using AOP in applicationContext.xml.
Everything just works fine. (commit, rollback)

My intention is to throw a specific exception inside of a jta-transaction.
This way the transaction should be rolled back and I get some detailed information about the cause of the rollback.

The problem is, that the only exception I can catch is a rollback-transaction thrown by atomikos, telling me, that the transaction was unexpectedly rolled back.

How can I get my own exception outside the transaction?

Here is a small example, because I don't know if my explanation was good enough.
This is only for demonstration what my intention is. Please don't comment any typos.

A specific exception (might be some standard exception as well):

```
public class MySpecialException extends Exception {
    public MySpecialException(String someInfo) {
        super(someInfo);
    }
}
```

An interface declareing a method which declares to throw the exception:

```
public interface MyInterface {
    Object someJtaTransactionMethod(String param) throws MySpecialException;
}
```

A class implementing the interface:

```
public class MyClass implements MyInterface {
    Object someJtaTransactionMethod(String param) throws MySpecialException {

        // some operations with some errorstate detected
        // so throw the exception:
        throw new MySpecialException("Things went terribly wrong!");

        // some other code
    }
}
```

And some code that calls the function and catches the exceptions.

```
public class Caller {

    @Autowired
    private MyInterface callee;

    public void test() {
        try {
            callee.someJtaTransactionMethod("Some test");
        } catch (MySpecialException mex) {
            // I want to get here
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // but I only get here
        }
    }
}
```

Is this possible at all?

UPDATE: Of course I had a look at the exception cause. The exception itself is of org.springframework.transaction.UnexpectedRollbackException. The cause is of class javax.transaction.RollbackTransaction and has a cause com.atomikos.icatch.RollbackException.

I think what happens is, that atomikos notices the exception and performs a rollback (as desired), but then atomikos (maybe other jta-implementations as well) throws an exception indicating that the transaction was rolled back (unexpectedly) and my exception is gone.

UPDATE 2: Funny thing is, that if I haven't done anything that has to be rolledback, I can catch my exception as desired!

UPDATE 3 and SOLUTION: JB Nizet pointed me to the solution. In fact my transaction wasN#t rolled back as I suspected, but because of the reason for me to throw my exception, I got an contraint violation and thus atomikos threw its exception on commit. Now that I configured my transaction to rollback for my exceptions everything works as expected and desired.

Comment: I don't know Atomikos, but could it be that they catch your exception and throw their own with your's as its causion? Have you analyzed the return of the getCause() Method of the Exception (from your second catch)?

Comment: Yes I had a look at the exception in detail (more than once during development) and I tried to debug into it, but I couldn't find anything... Updated post

Comment: Can you provide the stack trace and the versions of the frameworks you're using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is your exception a runtime exception or a checked exception?

Spring rollbacks by default if a runtime exception is thrown, and commits by default if a checked exception is thrown.

From the stack trace, it seems that your exception is a checked exception, so Spring tries to commit, but can't because the JTA TM (Atomikos) refuses to commit (because of a timeout, for example).

So, if you want this exception to cause a rollback, make it a runtime exception or declare it in the `rollbackFor` attribute of the @Transactional annotation. If it must not cause a rollback, then try to discover why Atomikos refuses to commit (too short timeout, something else... the logs could help).

Comment: Some interesting information. Usually if I had a exception like this, I debugged into atomikos and found the real cause (for example some hibernate or jdbc exception). I'll continue examining this issue tomorrow morning..... can't keep my eyes open anymore.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You saved my day. I just changed my Exception to inherit from RuntimeException and now everything works as desired. I didn't notice before that atomikos did't roll back when I threw my own exception and because of the exception-throwing I somehow wasn't able to debug into atomikos yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a type to me as you throw a MySpecialException that inherits from Exception instead of MyException?

Otherwise catch MySpecialException instead of MyException.

Comment: I already said this is only a example and that typos aren't the problem. My real code compiles and definitly tries to catch the right exception (otherwise the compiler would tell me...) corrected it...